# unable to move card list to left

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I'm trying to move my cards to the left to eliminate the space in the left margin.

[image]

I can't seem to move the cards closer to the left to eliminate the space in the left margin.
And I'm trying to add the title next to the avatar and the description at the bottom.

```html
<ion-item *ngSwitchDefault>
  <ion-card-content style="margin-left: 1px;" class="lists">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let topic of groupTopics">
      <ion-card style="width: 280px; height: 150px; margin: 1px; margin-left: 2px;" [ngSwitch]="topic.photoUrl">
        <ion-avatar *ngSwitchDefault slot="start">
          <img [src]="topic.photoUrl" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-avatar *ngSwitchCase="'false'">
          <img src="assets/img/add-an-image.png" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>
          <h2>{{topic.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{topic.description}}</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: It seems weird to me that you are putting an ion-list of ion-cards inside of an ion-card-content element. The ion-card-content element is intended to be a child element only of ion-card.

Comment: You could use a grid inside ion-card after `ion-avatar` to align your title and description